# How to reduce time (from 9am to 5pm)? Timepicker addon

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-ui-timepicker

I use http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#time').datetimepicker({ showSecond: false,dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',timeFormat: 'hh:mm',minDate: new Date() });
});
</script>
```

.......

```
<p><label for="id_time">Date:</label> <input type="text" name="time" id="time" /></p>
```

.......

How to reduce time (from 9am to 5pm)?

Answer (score 1):

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#rest_examples

```
$('#time').timepicker({
    ampm: true,
    hourMin: 9,
    hourMax: 17
});
```